# ggplot secondary y axes showing z scores using sec_axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axes

ggplot2 now allows for adding a secondary y-axis if it is a one-to-one transformation of the primary axis.

For my graph, I would like to plot the original units on the left y-axis and z-scores on the right y-axis, but I am having trouble working out how to do this in practice.

The [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/sec_axis.html) suggests this secondary axes are added using the sec_axis() function e.g.,

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+10))
```

creates a second y-axis 10 units higher than the first.

Z-scores [can be created in R using the scale() function](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-centering-variables-and-generating-z-scores-with-the-scale-function/). So I assumed I could do something like this to get a second y-axis displaying z-scores:

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(scale(~.)))
```

However, this returns a "invalid first argument" error.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I think it's `~scale(.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the z-score transformation formula. This works well:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
df <- data.frame(val = c(1:30), var = rnorm(30, 10,2))
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data = df, aes( x = val, y = var))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous("variable", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./ sd(df$var) - mean(df$var)/ sd(df$var), "standarized variable"))
p
```

Or :

```
p + scale_y_continuous("variable", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scale(.), "standarized variable"))
```

[image]